# python: printing colored string not working properly

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, colors

I have simple python script to read file and print it line by line, where comments (lines starting with `#`) are printed in color

```
cat file.txt
# asdf
1234
```

my python code:

```
for ln in file
    if COMMENT.match(ln):
        print "%s%s%s" % ('\033[01;32m', ln, '\033[0m'),
    else:
        print ln,
```

now, strangely, while the regex matching and coloring itself works fine, the `print` behaves in a way, I cannot explain. This is what gets printed:

```
# asdf
 1234
```

The first line is printed green, but notice the one extra space character on the next line, added in front of `1234`. This extra space is added every time, when previous line was colored.

Where is this extra space coming from, and how can i get rid of it ?

For completeness, here is my  `re.compile` expresssion which I am using in the snippet. But that seems to be working fine.

```
COMMENT = re.compile(r'^#.*$')
```

As a side note:

Have I chosen the right approach for coloring line. Or is there a better way doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line includes a newline character, but you use `print` with a `,` to prevent `print` from adding an extra newline. However, the `,` adds a *space* instead, so in the end you print `line\n<space>` each time, inserting a space before the next.

Instead of using `,`, remove the newline from `ln` and have `print` add one:

```
for ln in file:
    ln = ln.rstrip('\n')
    if COMMENT.match(ln):
        print "%s%s%s" % ('\033[01;32m', ln, '\033[0m')
    else:
        print ln
```

Comment: your suggested solution works. Thanks. But I still don't understand why the space character gets added. And why only in the first print, and not the second. Could you please explain, or point me where I can read about this?

Comment: @MartinVegter: `print` adds it each time you used `print ...,` before and did not write anything else to stdout. So `print 'foo',` then `print 'bar'` will add a space just before `'bar'` because you used a comma with the preceding `print`.

Answer (score 1):

for this simple job, no need to use `regex`. you can use `str.startswith`

try this:

```
with open("yourFile") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        if line.startswith("#"):
            print "%s%s%s" % ('\033[01;32m', line, '\033[0m')
        else:
             print line
```

Comment: You removed the `,` but not the extra newline. The regex may be more complex than just matching the `#` at the start (it may allow for whitespace for example).

Comment: @MartijnPieters added strip to remove newline, code works fine now, i checked

Comment: But the whitespace at the start can be significant. If this is Python code you just removed the indentation.

Comment: @Hackaholic - thanks for the suggestion, `line.startswith("#")` is much simpler than regex matching.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but if u see the COMMENT regex re.compile(r'^#.*$'), it starts with anchor, so # will be in stat of line, i dont think there will be a space in comment line here

Comment: @Hackaholic: true, but you strip **all** lines.

Comment: yeaa, got you now, so i can put strip after condition , thanks brother. Updated the code

Comment: If you are going to strip *just* the newline, you may as well do it before the condition. And use `str.rstrip()` since the newline will only be at the end when reading from a file, Python doesn't need to do the extra work of looking for it at the start of each line too.